# Prove that an equation with two integer variables has no solution

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

$$\dfrac{(2n)!}{((6k)n!(2^n)+1)} = n^2$$

How will you prove that it has no solution if $n$ and $k$ are integers?

Comment: In the denominator, is the 6k part of the factorial? i.e is it $(6k)\cdot n!$ or on the other hand is it $(6kn)!$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath Appreciate, edited! 6k * (n!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that I am mistaken, but:

For $n=0,1$, the claim is obviously true.

$(2n)!$ is divisible by $n^2$ (since it has factors $2n$ and $n$). So you can divide both sides by $n^2$, so that the right hand side becomes 1.

If $k\leq0$, then the assertion is clearly wrong. Otherwise we have an odd number that equals $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n}$. If $n\geq2$, this cannot hold (count the factors of 2 in $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n}$).

But again, it is quite late where I am now, and this may be not as easy. :)

Comment: Actually, unless $n=0$, $(2n)!/n^2$ is always even because there's the remaining factor of $2$ from $2n$. So for $n\geqslant1$ there are no solutions for the reason that you explained. And for $n=0$, we can't divide, but the equality obviously doesn't hold either.

Comment: True, will edit!